# Python ZipFile module problem when file is encrypted

Tags: python-3.x, zip

I have the following short program

```
from zipfile import ZipFile
procFile1 ="C:\\Temp\\XLFile-Demo.zip"
procFile2 ="C:\\Temp2\\XLFile-Demo-PW123.zip"

# Unencrypted file
print ("Unencrypted file")
myzip1 = ZipFile(procFile1)
print (myzip1.infolist())
myzip1.extractall("C:\\Temp")

# Encrypted File
print ("Encrypted file")
myzip2 = ZipFile(procFile2)
print (myzip2.infolist())
myzip2.setpassword(bytes('123', 'utf-8'))
myzip2.extractall("C:\\Temp2")enter code here
```

At this [Amazon Drive link](https://www.amazon.com/clouddrive/share/T3VxyIfeO3sWgDQeIqw56gVB6X6LZZlC58rsNmIrrCy) are the two files. They are identical except that one zip is protected with the password *123*.

Executing the above code successfully extracts the unencrypted one but raises the error **NotImplementedError: That compression method is not supported** for the other.

```
Unencrypted file
[<ZipInfo filename='XLFile-Demo.xlsx' compress_type=deflate external_attr=0x20 file_size=31964 compress_size=29252>]

Encrypted file
[<ZipInfo filename='XLFile-Demo.xlsx' compress_type=99 external_attr=0x20 file_size=31964 compress_size=29280>]
```

Am I doing anything wrong from my end?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error came up when the file was zipped using WinRar's ZIP option. I installed 7Zip and it is working.

The .infolist for the 7Zip file is the following:

```
[<ZipInfo filename='XLFile-Demo.xlsx' compress_type=deflate external_attr=0x20 file_size=31964 compress_size=29340>]
```

Incidentally WinRar can handle this file and 7Zip can correctly process the encrypted Zip archive created by WinRar.